# How to check what case is selected with radio button Win 32 api

Tags: c++, winapi, radio-button

I am using win 32 api in C++ to devellop a desktop app.
At on point I want to use a radio button with two case, and depending on what case is selected by the user I want to create a dialogBox.

I use a ressource file to create the dialog box that contains the radio button :

```
IDD_INPUT DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 150, 150
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Pricing Input"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    RADIOBUTTON     "Historical Data",IDC_HISTO,20, 20, 50,14
    RADIOBUTTON     "User Inpu",IDC_USER,90,20,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Ok",IDC_VALID,60,100,50,14
END
```

The dialog box is created as follow :

```
hWndDlgBox = CreateDialog(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_INPUT), hWnd, (DLGPROC)DlgInput);
```

And the DlgInput procedure is something like:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgInput(HWND hWnDlg, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_VALID:
        {
            if (GetDlgItem(hWnDlg, IDC_USER)) {
                // Open dialog box x
            }
            else {
                //Open dialog box y 
            }
            SendMessage(hWnDlg, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);

        }
        break;
        }
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnDlg);
        hWndDlgBox = NULL;
        break;

    default:
        return FALSE;
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

So in the IDC_VALID case I want to check the value of the radio button, I tried using the GetDlgItem function but I don't really understand what value it returns. I saw that it's possible to use the BM_GETCHECK message but I'm not sure how to use it.
Also when I click on one case the dialog box closes and I don't know why.

Can someone explain to me how the radio button work ?

Comment: [`IsDlgButtonChecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isdlgbuttonchecked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to send the [BM_GETCHECK message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-getcheck?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to the control and check the return value. And you will need the HWND of your control, to get that from the control ID, you could try to call [GetDlgItem()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem?redirectedfrom=MSDN).